# Getting Django Logger to Create a Log File for Me

Tags: python, django, logging

I have my logger setup as thus:

```
...'handlers': {
    # with debug on, print log messages to the console
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',  # error message level
        'filters': ['require_debug_true'],  # choose filter
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',  # iostreams
        'formatter': 'verbose'  # format of messages
    },
    # with debug on, log messages in dev file
    'development_logfile': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',  # open and close files
        'filename': '/Users/Michael/venvs/wabi/wabi_clean/dev.log'),
        'formatter': 'verbose'
    },
    # with debug off, log messages in prod file
    'production_logfile': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',  # have file backups
        'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'prod.log'),
        'maxBytes': 1024*1024*100,  # 100MB (max file size)
        'backupCount': 5,  # number of backup files
        'formatter': 'simple'
    },
    'dba_logfile': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false', 'require_debug_true'],
        'class': 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler',  # read into more
        'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dba.log'),
        'formatter': 'simple'
    },...
```

Where it says `'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'prod.log'),`, this does not work. I need to put a full path to an already existent file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the entry with `'filename': '/Users/Michael/venvs/wabi/wabi_clean/dev.log'` work? If so, what is the value of `BASE_DIR` in the environment you are running?

Comment: Yes, @MrName & it’s that same path minus ‘dev.log’.  I’m not understanding though why it doesn’t work if the file is not already created

Comment: What you meant by * this does not work.* ? Does it rais any error?

Comment: Haha, that was my next question. By "does not work" I assume you mean the file simply never shows up? You also seem to indicate that everything will work if the file already exists, so the issue is simply that it is not CREATING the file?

Comment: Yes, @MrName that is the perfect way to put it! It doesn’t create the file

Comment: Okay, and just to confirm, when you are testing the file creation, you are definitely emitting `ERROR` level logging calls and the application is not in debug mode?

Comment: @MrName yes, this is the case... Could it have something with permissions not allowing the Django user to create files to the directory? -- I seem to have answered my own question.. How do I check what user is trying to write to the directory?